# Конвертировать список словарей в объекты dataclass

Tags: python, dataclass

Есть список словарей:

```
a = [{"id": 12683, "text": "шла саша по шоссе"}, {"id": 8384, "text": "ехал грека через реку"}, {"id": 3974, "text": "мы пришли домой"}, {"id": 2456, "text": "мама мыла машу"}..]
```

Используя dataclass, необходимо сделать так, чтобы можно было обращаться к полям этих словарей через объекты класса.

Есть небольшая наработка

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Texts:    
    id: int
    text: str
```

Но не понимаю как дальше работать с этим

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно точно так же создать список, только из экземпляров класса.

```
b = [Texts(d["id"], d["text"]) for d in a]
```

В переменной `b` будет:

```
[Texts(id=12683, text='шла саша по шоссе'),
 Texts(id=8384, text='ехал грека через реку'),
 Texts(id=3974, text='мы пришли домой'),
 Texts(id=2456, text='мама мыла машу')]
```

Пример обращения:

```
print(b[1].text)
# Напечатает "ехал грека через реку"
```

Answer (score 1):

У `dataclass` есть много особых настроек (можно почитать [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/415829/)) но если вы не планируете что-то подобное использовать, то можно обойтись `namedtuple` (коллекция также будет неизменяемой):

```
from collections import namedtuple 

a = [{"id": 12683, "text": "шла саша по шоссе"}, 
     {"id": 8384, "text": "ехал грека через реку"}, 
     {"id": 3974, "text": "мы пришли домой"}, 
     {"id": 2456, "text": "мама мыла машу"}]

Texts = namedtuple("Texts", ["id", "text"])
b = [Texts(**d) for d in a]

'''
[Texts(id=12683, text='шла саша по шоссе'),
 Texts(id=8384, text='ехал грека через реку'),
 Texts(id=3974, text='мы пришли домой'),
 Texts(id=2456, text='мама мыла машу')]
'''
```

пример обращения:

```
print(*[i.text.title() for i in b], sep='\n')

'''
Шла Саша По Шоссе
Ехал Грека Через Реку
Мы Пришли Домой
Мама Мыла Машу
'''
```